# 'attrs' property in angular directive is not working properly

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to write a very simple directive which involves setting a property based off one of the attributes that it is provided.  The issue I'm facing is that the value of the `attrs` object is not being consistently recognized within the `link` function.

Here is the grand total of what I'm currently trying to achieve :

```
angular.module('directives').directive('wikiNotes',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        templateUrl: 'common/directives/wiki-notes.tpl.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            console.log(attrs.openEdit); //true

            if(attrs.openEdit===true){
                console.log('open edit'); //not called
            }
        }
    };
});
```

The `console.log(attrs.openEdit)` is showing as true, but then the `console.log` in the `if` block is not getting called.  Am I missing something very obvious or is this a quirk with angular directives?

Comment: I discovered the issue.  `attrs.openEdit` is given 'true' as a string, not as a boolean.  Apologies for jumping the gun and posting.

Comment: This is a good finding. You must post it as answer.

Comment: All attributes get serialized as a string. That can be pretty annoying when you want to pass in a reference to an existing object instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider adding this attribute in your directive scope section?
I think it is more in the Angular philosophy, but this imply you create a new scope for your directive.

```
angular.module('directives')
.directive('wikiNotes',function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            openEdit: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'common/directives/wiki-notes.tpl.html',
        link: function(scope) {

            console.log(scope.openEdit); //true

            if(scope.openEdit===true){
                console.log('open edit'); //should be a boolean
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Here is a JS fiddle that demonstrate it works.
https://jsfiddle.net/c8mn9wka/3/